# Restify Cross Origin Basic Auth with AJAX

Tags: restify

HTTP Basic Auth is working great when calling from my REST client. However, the app that is consuming the API is built w/ Backbone.

We tried overriding Backbone sync to pass along the Authorization header but it is failing on an options call -- from what I understand a `preflight` call to see if cross origin calls are allowed. And it's important to note that this is not unique to Backbone, this happens with any cross-origin AJAX call that has modified headers.

**Response Screenshot:** http://cl.ly/image/0j2v240A0p2f

I've also tried modifying the fullResponse (full_response.js) plugin bundled w/ Restify (by adding `Authorization` to the `ALLOW_HEADERS` array.

```
var ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'Accept',
    'Accept-Version',
    'Content-Length',
    'Content-MD5',
    'Content-Type',
    'Date',
    'X-Api-Version',
    'X-Response-Time',
    'Authorization'
].join(', ');
```

This is one of the few things left before being able to push to production. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable cross origin resource sharing on your server: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Restify fullResponse plugin enables CORS by default. We're good on that front. Cross origin calls have been working great up until we added a custom header -- then it broke. I have a feeling that it has something to do with OPTIONS not being enabled.

Comment: The OPTIONS request queries the server to check if CORS is enabled before sending the actual request. Your server must need some other switch to be toggled on to properly respond to OPTIONS requests.

Answer (score 1):

Last version of restify implement natively CORS... so you can add something like that (fullReponse seems to be needed when you use CORS:

```
shoorkServer.use(restify.CORS());
shoorkServer.use(restify.fullResponse());
```

If you use Backbone or jquery you should modify server side like that :

```
shoorkServer.use(restify.CORS( {credentials: true} ));
shoorkServer.use(restify.fullResponse());
```

And use credentials with jquery :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    }
});
```